# A "Search" mysql query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query where I can search the TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS

```
$catglobal_sql = "
 select p.*, 
   case when 
     p.specials_new_products_price >= 0.0000 
     and p.expires_date > Now() 
     and p.status != 0 
   then p.specials_new_products_price 
   else p.products_price 
   end price 
 from ".TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS." p 
   INNER JOIN ".TABLE_STORES." s ON s.blog_id = p.blog_id 
 where 
   MATCH (p.products_name,p.products_description) AGAINST ('%".$search_key."%') 
   OR p.products_name like '%".$search_key."%' 
   order by p.products_date_added DESC, p.products_name";
```

The issue here is that, when I search with phrases like `Cotton Shirts` it displays correct results. However, when I only input a single word like `Cotton` it displays no results instead of displaying the same as when you input a phrase like `Cotton Shirts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use * instead of % as a wildcard when using MATCH ... AGAINST ...
So the match part of your code should look like:

> ...
>
> MATCH (p.products_name,p.products_description) AGAINST ('*".$search_key."*')
>
> ...

In MATCH the wildcards are slightly different

#### To match zero or more characters use

- In MATCH '*'
- In LIKE '%'

#### To match any single character use

- In MATCH '?'
- In LIKE '_'